# How do I make generic type and concrete type interchangeable?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing an immutable binary tree class where all of the methods (Insert, Remove, RotateLeft, etc) return a new instance of a tree instead of modifying it in place.

I'm going to be creating lots of different implementations of tree: Avl tree, red-black tree, splay tree, etc. I have the following:

```
public class AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T>
    where TreeType : AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    protected abstract TreeType CreateNode(TreeType left, T value, TreeType right);
    protected abstract T Value { get; }
    protected abstract TreeType Left { get; }
    protected abstract TreeType Right { get; }
    protected abstract bool IsNil();

    public TreeType Insert(T item)
    {
        if (this.IsNil())
        {
            return CreateNode(this, item, this);
            // ^ doesn't compile, can't convert type
            // AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> to type TreeType
        }
        else
        {
            int compare = item.CompareTo(this.Value);
            if (compare < 0)
            {
                return CreateNode(this.Left.Insert(item), this.Value, this.Right);
            }
            else if (compare > 0)
            {
                return CreateNode(this.Left, this.Value, this.Right.Insert(Value));
            }
            else
            {
                return this;
                // ^ doesn't compile, can't converrt type
                // AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> to type TreeType
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea here is that AbstractBinaryTree is a tree node -- more than that, it is the same type as `TreeType`. If I can get the above base class working correctly, then I can write something like this:

```
public class AvlTree<T> : AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T>
{
    public override AvlTree<T> Insert(T item) { return Balance(base.Insert(item)); }
}
```

so that my Insert method returns `AvlTree<T>` instead of `AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T>`. However I can't even get this far because the base class doesn't compile.

**How do I pass an instance of AbstractBinaryTree into a method which takes a type `TreeType`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really have an answer - just a few hints that may be useful. I think this would work in a language that has a concept called *self types* (I can't find and good site to link!). Anyway, a self type means that you can declare an abstract base class (say `A`) and it can have a method that returns the *self type*. When creating an inherited class (say `B`) the uses of the *self type* will refer to `B` (which is interesting, because the base class didn't know about this class). For C# 4 fans, the *self type* is covariant.

Anyway, you could try searching for a way to emulate *self types* in C# using generics...

Another pointer is to an article that I've seen some time ago. As far as I remember, it used generics in a similar way as you do, so maybe it can give you some hint how to solve the problem.

- [The Expression problem revisited](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~madst/tool/papers/expression.pdf) by Mads Torgersen (now in the C# team!)

Comment: +1: very interesting :) Although C# doesn't support this out of the box, its very easy to simulate with abstract classes. For example, base class `A<T> where T : A<T>` can have an abstract method `T Self()`, and a derived class `B : A<B>` can implement the method as `override B Self() { return this; }`. I actually have an implementation of this sort of strategy here (http://pastebin.com/PussQDmN), and it works perfectly exactly as advertised.

Comment: +answer: emulating self-types with generics is ultimately the solution I settled on :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T>`

```
    public abstract class AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T>
            where TreeType : AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T>
            where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            protected abstract TreeType CreateNode(AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> left, T value, AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> right);
            protected abstract T Value { get; }
            protected abstract TreeType Left { get; }
            protected abstract TreeType Right { get; }
            protected abstract bool IsNil();

            public virtual AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> Insert(T item)
            {
                if (this.IsNil())
                {
                    return CreateNode(this.Left, item, this.Right);
                    // ^ doesn't compile, can't convert type 
                    // AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> to type TreeType 
                }
                else
                {
                    int compare = item.CompareTo(this.Value);
                    if (compare < 0)
                    {
                        return CreateNode(this.Left.Insert(item), this.Value, this.Right);
                    }
                    else if (compare > 0)
                    {
                        return CreateNode(this.Left, this.Value, this.Right.Insert(Value));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return this;
                        // ^ doesn't compile, can't converrt type 
                        // AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> to type TreeType 
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

    public class AvlTree<T> : AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T>
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        public override AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T> Insert(T item)
        {
            return base.Insert(item);
        }
}
```

---

With Balance() to cast

```
private AvlTree<T> Balance(AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T> item)
{
    return (AvlTree<T>)item;
}

public override AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T> Insert(T item)
{
    return Balance(Insert(item));
}
```

Comment: `where T : AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T>, IComparable<T>` in the `AvlTree<T>` should probably just be `where T : IComparable<T>`

Comment: Also with `private AvlTree<T> Balance(AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T> tree);`, you can have the desired `public override AvlTree<T> Insert(T item)`

Comment: You will have to cast the return from Insert() to get to the more specific type. Its a strange one...

Comment: Her desired override was `return Balance(base.Insert(item));`, so her Balance function can theoretically act on an AbstractBinaryTree<> and return an AvlTree<T> (since CreateNode returns TreeType, and `this` is also TreeType in this case).

Comment: I think I can make this work, but it seems like a weird set of methods to override. In particular, the method `abstract TreeType CreateNode(AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> left, T value, AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T> right);` seems to reveal a lot about the underlying implementation of the class.

Comment: With the new edit, I'm not sure I like the way AvlTree.Insert returns AbstractBinaryTree instead of AvlTree. For example, imagine if AvlTree has a public function called Height or some other useful method; since Insert returns a different data type, clients don't see the Height property without a cast of the return type, which doesn't seem exactly reasonable for a generic method.

Answer (score 2):

Oh wow, I make things too hard for myself, but in any case the solution is really super simple:

`AbstractBinaryTree` already contains a Left, Value, and Right property, so I can just create a copy of the current node using `CreateNode(this.Left, this.Value, this.Right)` instead of trying to return `this`:

```
public abstract class AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T>
    where TreeType : AbstractBinaryTree<TreeType, T>
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    protected abstract TreeType CreateNil();
    protected abstract TreeType CreateNode(TreeType left, T value, TreeType right);

    protected abstract T Value { get; }
    protected abstract TreeType Left { get; }
    protected abstract TreeType Right { get; }
    protected abstract bool IsNil();

    public virtual TreeType Insert(T item)
    {
        if (this.IsNil())
        {
            // can't return 'this', so just creating a new nil node
            TreeType nil = CreateNil();
            return CreateNode(nil, item, nil);
        }
        else
        {
            int compare = item.CompareTo(this.Value);
            if (compare < 0)
            {
                return CreateNode(this.Left.Insert(item), this.Value, this.Right);
            }
            else if (compare > 0)
            {
                return CreateNode(this.Left, this.Value, this.Right.Insert(Value));
            }
            else
            {
                // can't return 'this', so just creating a new node with a
                // copy of the same values
                return CreateNode(this.Left, this.Value, this.Right);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class AvlTree<T> : AbstractBinaryTree<AvlTree<T>, T>
{
    public override AvlTree<T> Insert(T value) { return Balance(base.Insert(value)); }
}
```

The implementation of AvlTree works out beautifully because we recursively insert into the tree on the way down, and balance the tree as the callstack unwinds.

If anyone can suggest a way that let's me reuse `this` instead of allocating a new object with a copy of its values, I'd like to hear it, but for right now this seems to work.

Comment: Great! Yes it seemed to want either 'CreateNode' or 'this', which was making it difficult.

Comment: This is quite slick. :)  Also, if you want to get rid of the tree copies, `if (this.IsNil()) { return CreateNode(this.Left, item, this.Right); }` should be fine (assuming Nil.Left is Nil), which would also get rid of the need for CreateNil(), and you could probably just as cast `this` even if you're really paranoid about type safety on your cast return to not (usually) need the copy on insert equal... `return (this as TreeType) ?? CreateNode(this.Left, this.Value, this.Right)`